# What counts as patents of "Foreign Origin" in the USPTO statistics?

Tags: uspto, international, statistics

The [U.S. Patent Statistics Chart
Calendar Years 1963 - 2019](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/ac/ido/oeip/taf/us_stat.htm) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200530174604/https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/ac/ido/oeip/taf/us_stat.htm))  distinguish Applications of "U.S. Origin" from Applications of "Foreign Origin".

What counts as patents of "Foreign Origin" in the USPTO statistics?  For example, if for a given patent 1 assignee is located outside the United States and 1 assignee is located in the United States, does that count as a patent of "Foreign Origin" or a patent of "U.S.  Origin"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Frequently Asked Questions About Patent Statistics](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/ac/ido/oeip/taf/faq.htm):
"the PTMT Patent Technology Monitoring Team] and USPTO Annual Fiscal Year Reports use the residence of the first-named inventor to determine the origin of a patent"

See also the [list of reports](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/ac/ido/oeip/taf/reports.htm):
"The totals are broken down by origin (patent origin is determined by the residence of the first-named inventor), either U.S. or foreign."

The ownership of the patent (assignee(s)) is not used to determine origin of the patents in these reports.